# An Inside Out Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, cryptic-crosswords

The answer is a single English word. Figure out the word and explain the clues.

> Nature's God leads with legal men next.
>   Dichotomies  joined like a page filled with text.
>   Add a digit to five, dot both i's with ink.
>   Announcers divided by that which should link.
>   Pour liquid on life's thread in a right to left track.
>   Sorrowful slumber when taken aback.

Hint:

> It has to be "dichotomies" "opposites" doesn't work. Don't know what I was thinking with that edit.

Comment: I looked up, "NOAAPS" and I got nothing. Good riddle.

Comment: So now we're looking at PANDAS.  Odd...

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Perhaps I *like* pandas. What is so odd about that? What have you got against pandas?

Comment: Sigh - this puzzle is *Panda*monium!

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Are you American? I'm not, but I wrote this for an American audience and there are a couple of cultural references that might be difficult for a non-American to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I have solved all the hints!

> Pandas!

Nature's God leads with legal men next.

> The Greek god of the wild (**Pan**) + district attorneys (**DAs**)

Dichotomies joined like a page filled with text.

> Black and white, like a newspaper.

Add a digit to five, dot both i's with ink.

> Pandas have six fingers (five and a thumb) and black-spotted eyes.

Announcers divided by that which should link.

> Public Address systems (**PAs**) split by a common linking word (**and**)

Pour liquid on life's thread in a right to left track.

> Tree sap backwards (**PAS**) covering DNA backwards (**AND**)

Sorrowful slumber when taken aback.

> Reverse of a sad nap (**PANDAS**)

Bonus:

> Of course, the jumbled acrostic NDAAPS. Taking letters from alternate sides starting from the center (title -- "Inside Out"), we get PANDAS.
>
>  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ybFyXKqxlo) is a nice extra title reference. :P

Comment: Well done! If you spelled that word from the inside out, what would it look like?

Comment: Of course. Nicely done. I left my original reference for flavor.  Nothing like an obscure Italian auto advert to spice up P.SE